# How to plot the result of svm (11-D featured data) in Octave/Matlab?

Tags: octave, libsvm

I tried it using `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid` as in [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649384/svm-visualization-in-matlab). 
But I am getting error as "out of memory". Kindly help in plotting the result of svm (using Octave interface LibSVM).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get this error message very likely because your system is running out of memory. If you want a better answer you have to provide your code (or even better:a minimalistic reproducible example) so we can see the parameter you used for ndgrid.

Have you tried to separately calculate the amount of memory needed for your task?

Comment: Thank You. No, I have not calculated the memory required. I have 11 features for 3 class data (152 training and 61 test data).I was trying it like- [a,b,c,...k]=ndgrid([min(x(:,1)):0.1:max(x(:,1)],..,min(x:,11):0.1:max(:,11)]); 
to get rid of error, changed to 
[a,b,c,d]=ndgrid([min(x(:,1)):max(x(:,1)],...[min(x:,4):max(:,4)]);...[i,j,k]=ndgrid([min(x(:,9)):max(x(:,9)],...[min(x:,11):max(:,11)]); 
But now I am getting different dimensions for last two (j,k) and I cannot merge those into single variable to plot the result.
How to plot svm result for this? Kindly help.